# thomson tg782 and no-ip 

Tags: localhost

I was setting up the TCP port of IIS(5.1) to 28960 and when I type in the browser 192.168.1.1:28960 will not work.  Where is the problem?

**Edit:** when I type localhost:28960 it works, but when I type 192.168.1.1:28960 it doesn't work

**Edit:** ok..but I have new problem, this is my ip adress 78.0.77.160 , but when I type 78.0.77.160:28960 it doesn't work, or I can't see my localhost welcome page?

Answer (score 0):

What does "will not work" mean, exactly?  Do you get a particular error message?  A timeout?

Have you checked various firewall settings for blocked ports?

Does it work on any other port, including port 80?

Comment: when i type 192.168.1.1 it open router admin page..
whein i type 192.168.1.1:28960 i get a timeout error page

Comment: If 192.168.1.1 is the address of your router, then I think you just learned all you need know.  I seriously doubt IIS is running on your router.

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing to `127.0.0.1:28960`.  Based on your comments from @abelenky's answer (and his response), `192.168.1.1` seems to be the IP address of your router.  (Makes sense, it's a pretty standard router IP address.)  Without going into a lot of effort to find your computer's IP address (though I suggest you look that up), `127.0.0.1` is standard for `localhost` and will browse to the local computer from which it's requested.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, what's probably happening is you are trying to browse to your *external* IP address, which is technically *not* your computer's IP address.  Your router is likely acting as a NAT box (pretty standard) and providing internal IP addresses.  That external IP address is most likely assigned to your router's WAN interface or perhaps even your cable/dsl/etc. modem.  Your router's LAN interface is set to `192.168.1.1` and your router probably runs a DHCP service which sets computers in your network to IP addresses in the `192.168.1.2-255` range.

So what's happening is that when you try to go to your public IP address, your computer sends the request out to the router which loops back on its WAN interface.  Your router isn't running a server on that port, nor is it configured to forward that port to your computer, so it times out.  The most immediate solution would be to use the admin interface for your router to configure port-forwarding to send traffic on port `28960` to your computer.  To do this, you'll need to know your computer's IP address.  (If I remember my Windows correctly, it's something like `ipconfig` on the Command Prompt.)

Comment: ok..but i have new problem, this is my ip adress http://78.0.77.160 , but when i type http://78.0.77.160:28960 it doesn't work, or i can't see my localhost welcome page..?